# Out of memory when creating multiple PDFs using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am creating several hundred reports within excel and saving them as PDF. If I remove the save to PDF routine it will go through all reports. When I add the routine back in it is very flaky, sometimes making it to 20 sometimes to 60 and every now and then though all 250.
When it errors out is gives a memory error message that shows up as a plan white box. I press Cntrl-C to copy this and then paste it into notepad to see the error message which is the memory error.

I have also tried saving the report as a Jpg but have the same issue with memory.

The PDF files that are created are about 186KB, the excel file is 466KB.
Using Office 365 64bit and have 16gig of ram on my computer and over 600 gig of free disk space.

Below is the code I am using the generate the PDFs, any suggestions?

I have looked through other posts on this subject but have not seen an answer and they were all several years old.

```
Sub CreatePDFSave(sFileName As String)
Dim sPathFile As String
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheet5
sPathFile = Environ$("UserProfile") & "\Documents\"

sFileName = sPathFile & sFileName

wks.Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    sFileName & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Set wks = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are these several hundred reports individual file? If so, have you ensure each are closed after save as pdf? Also, what other steps you have taken to open the files?

Comment: This is one file that is running queries against SQL to produce the desired report. After each report is created it creates the PDF file needed. If I remove the PDF create part everything runs through. We have added "On Error goto 0" in the PDF sub routine and that seems to be working. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Do you remove/clear the `ActiveSheet` after each SQL query report? Do you also add `DoEvents` before/after each SQL query for Excel? Might also want to disable events and turn calculation to Manual so excel won't consume memory to update data.